# Not receiving Events via Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, ios14, skadnetwork

I have followed all the instructions for setting up the Facebook iOS SDK.

All I want to do is track install events on iPhone devices, so I can run Ads on iOS 14.

I have:

Added my iOS app to my Facebook account

Added the relevant key pairs to Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb{APP_ID}</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{APP_ID}</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>{CLIENT_ID}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{APP-NAME}</string>
```

Initialised the FB SDK on launch:

**MyApp.swift**

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Facebook Init
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true
    }
    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        // Facebook Init
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }
```

The Test Events section of Facebook says:

**Open your app and interact with it to start seeing activity.**

So I open the app - however there are no events showing up. I restart the app and still nothing.

Any idea what the problem may be? I feel like i'm missing something but can't figure out what.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I have the exact same problem. Events manager recognized my updated SDK, but failed to log any events for days.

Comment: same here, integrated everything in a couple of hours, but the "Test Events" section does not show anything...

Comment: It is still not solved. I contacted Facebook and they acknowledged the problem but do not know when it will get fixed.

Comment: @Zorgan Did you figure out the issue? In my case Events manager not recognizing my updated SDK. I already added the latest version of FBSDK 11.3.1

Comment: @Zorgan was this solved, I have the exact same problem

Comment: @Zorgan was this solved, I have the exact same problem

Comment: Hi all - unfortunately I never got this solved - so I didn't run ads.

Answer (score 2):

Posting incase this helps anybody else out

I got in touch with FB support- the problem was not opting-in to data collection for FB and IG for iOS ATS.

FB instructed to deleted both apps, opt in to allow tracking on both apps then you will be able to see the data populate when testing in the Events Manager.

Comment: Or, even easier: go to iOS Settings and allow tracking for both apps.

Comment: @ThomasWalther tried that prior to this solution, didn't work for me. The reinstall was the only thing that got test data showing up for me